# Inserting textbox into absolute positioned div using innerHTML causes weird bug on Chrome Mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I have an html document with a textbox and an empty div that will get a new textbox inserted on button click. When I insert a textbox into the div with absolute position, the other textbox dissappears. I've been able to reproduce the bug with minimal code. I've found that this bug occurs if both textbox value attributes are not empty and the div has position absolute or fixed. The bug surprisingly resolves if I set value attribute empty for any textbox. This happens on android chrome but not on desktop. What am I doing wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/z34e9wah/

```js
function newTextbox(){
   document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = '<input type="text" value="textbox2">';
}
```

```css
#myDiv{
   border:1px solid #000;
   position:absolute;
   width:200px;
   height:100px;
   top:50px;
   left:0px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="textbox1">

<div id="myDiv"></div>

<button onclick="newTextbox()">Create new textbox</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this correctly and you are trying to generate multiple input boxes inside your `<div>`, you are currently overriding the contents of your `<div>` each time you set the innerHTML. You could concatenate the current contents of the `<div>` with each new text field, as shown below.

```js
let i = 1;
function newTextbox(){
   let currentHTML = document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML;
   i++;
   document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = `${currentHTML}<input type="text" value="textbox${i}" /><br />`;
}
```

```css
#myDiv{
   border:1px solid #000;
   position:absolute;
   width:200px;
   height:100px;
   top:50px;
   left:0px;
   overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="textbox1" />

<div id="myDiv"></div>

<button onclick="newTextbox()">Create new textbox</button>
```

Comment: No I'm not trying to generate multiple input boxes. My problem is that the input box outside the div disappears when I insert an input box inside the div. Everything works fine on desktop but not on mobile chrome.